# Sharing a git repository between OS/X and Windows

Tags: git, version-control, newline

I have a git repository stored in a Dropbox folder, that I use to sync between systems running OS/X and Windows.

Since OS/X uses the line feed (LR) character for newlines and Windows uses carriage return and line feed (CR+LF) whenever I move between machines I see a bunch of non-contentful changes, which just modify the newline character.

Is there a good way to deal with this? Can I tell git to ignore the newline modifications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub has a helpful article about this:

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

In general, they suggest using `git config --global core.autocrlf true` on windows, and `git config --global core.autocrlf input` for OS X.